# Eclipse Installer > Eclipse IDE For Java Developers > Eclipse > Eclipse Marketplace > Kotlin > java.util.ArrayList?

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, configuration

Used equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022 to install Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2019-12 then invoked Eclipse and used Eclipse Marketplace to install Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.19. I created a Kotlin project. Using Package Explorer I expanded the contents of JRE System Library.

[image: Package Explorer expanded the contents of JRE System Library.]

I expected to see [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) be listed in order to use on
[kotlin-stdlib / kotlin.collections / ArrayList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html) . Is there some other step missing?

Comment: Those are modules, the 'java.util' package is in the  'java.base' module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That listing is showing the 'modules' in the JRE. Modules were introduced in Java 9.

The 'java.util' package is in the 'java.base' module as show in this screen shot:

[image: Expanded module list]